# Forcing spring hateoas to generate https links instead of http

Tags: https, spring-boot, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I'm using *spring-boot:1.3.3*, *spring-hateoas:0.19.0* and *spring-data-rest-core:2.4.4*.

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "projects" : [ {
      "status" : "ACTIVE",
      "storageRegion" : "US",
      "dataSize" : 96850,
      "freemiumUnits" : 1,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://example.com/x-region-us/api/data/projects/2c9f93b755359a4a015535c19b1f0006"
        },
        "project" : {
          "href" : "http://example.com/x-region-us/api/data/projects/2c9f93b755359a4a015535c19b1f0006"
        },
```

This is example of content served by spring-hateoas. After a while I switched my application to ***SSL***.

Problem comes when using **traverson.js** to *jump(hop)* through "_links". Error occures:

> traverson.min.js:2 Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://example.com/project-new' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested
>   an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://example.com/x-region-us/api/data/submittalActions'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Is there a way to force spring to generate ***HTTPS*** links over ***HTTP*** in *"_links"* part of json?

Comment: That happens automatically when you call the REST endpoint via `https`.

Comment: @zeroflagL It doesn't happen. I call endpoint via `https`, but all _href_ in _"_links"_ property are with `http` prefix...

Comment: Is there a proxy or web server in front of the application?

Comment: @zeroflagL there is nginx in front with every necessary headers set :/

Comment: I guess the client calls the nginx server via https which calls Spring Boot via http. That would lead to the result you described. There is one similar question  on SO with a comment or answer from a Spring developer. A certain header can be set AFAIR.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for that? I'm having the same problem but with Zuul instead of ngix

Comment: @phoenix7360 No, I haven't find any solution. I'm using both ngix and zuul. I have theory that some zuul interceptor is causing problem maybe :S

Comment: personally I think my problem comes from my setup. My zuul is behing an AWS ELB which receives traffic through https, decrypts it and sent HTTP to zuul. so perhaps this makes zuul think that it should be contacted via HTTP rather than HTTPS

Comment: i will post a separate question for this and will give you the link

Comment: @phoenix7360 interesting though. thanks

Comment: @Raca if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464001/zuul-behind-an-aws-elb-over-https-ssl

Answer (score 2):

If you use Apache Http Server, you need add in the config file this line:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

Comment: I think one should prefer the standardized version:
`RequestHeader set Forwarded: proto=https`
X-... headers are "experimental" in theory. Both versions are working though.

Comment: If the webserver/LB is forwarding the headers correctly, then you also need to add the property `server.forward-headers-strategy=FRAMEWORK` to `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Add the below headers to NginX

```
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix $http_x_forwarded_prefix;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_x_forwarded_host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme https;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
```